# How to make sure my object has their own x and y

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am guessing that there may be an answer about this on the internet somewhere but I can not find it. I am making a graphing calculator and I tried to make "plots" follow a certain function y = 2x. Though i can not seem to find out how to make the plots have their own x and y (their unique x and y).

```
function CreateDot() {
this.ix = 1; //this is the x value of the function and is also used in y = 2x
this.fy = this.ix * 2; //this is the y value of the funciton y = 2x

    this.newDot = function() {
//this is defining the x value of the plot and scaling the value to have it follow the grid
        this.x1 = spacing * this.ix;


// this is defining the y value of the plot and scaling the value to have it follow the grid
        this.y1 = 500 - spacing * this.fy; //


//this is the code for creating the "plot" which is a dot on the screen and red in colour
        stroke(255,0,0);
        strokeWeight(25);

//this is defining the position of the point with the values above x1 and y1
        point(this.x1,this.y1);


//this is supposed to allow the next value of x=2 in the function y = 2x and so allowing the next coordinates of the plot to be ( 2, 4 ) and the next dot (3, 6) and so on.
        this.ix = this.ix + 1;
}
}
```

I what I noticed is that after I made this a constructor function and put new dots into an array and limited it to 5, I ran it and one dot flew all the way to the right. I printed each of the objects x and y and they had the same values..

So my question is how do I make sure **Each object has their own unique x and y values?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is necessary to give all my code, then please do ask me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the function either on the prototype and call it that way, or you have to pass the dots as parameters to the update function:

```js
// Prototype
function CreateDot( spacing ) {
  this.ix = 1;
  this.fy = this.ix * 2;
  this.x1 = spacing * this.ix;
  this.y1 = 500 - spacing * this.fy;
}
CreateDot.prototype.addOne = function() {
  // this refers to: 'the dot you call addOne upon'.
  this.ix = this.ix + 1;
};
var myDot = new CreateDot( 250 );
console.log( 'before myDot.addOne() : ' + myDot.ix );
myDot.addOne();
  console.log( 'after myDot.addOne() : ' + myDot.ix );
// Seperate function
var addOne_f = function( dot ) {
  // this refers to 'the window instance', so you need to use the 'dot' parameter to refer to the dot.
  dot.ix = dot.ix + 1;
};
console.log( 'before addOne_f( myDot ) : ' + myDot.ix );
addOne_f( myDot );
console.log( 'after addOne_f( myDot ) : ' + myDot.ix );

//  Inside an array:
var dots = [
  new CreateDot( 200 ),
  new CreateDot( 225 ),
  new CreateDot( 250 )
];
//  Update all dots
dots.forEach( dot => dot.addOne());
//  Update the second dot again to show they're not linked
dots[ 1 ].addOne();
console.log( dots.map( dot => dot.ix ));
```

Comment: May you explain what prototypes do or what they are exactly? I am pretty new to coding...

Comment: or is it just a term for what you just did. I am deeply confused now. haha

Comment: They create a special function called a 'method' which is shared between all the different instances of the class. So all the dots would share that function between them. Inside such a method, `this` will refer to the current instance, so the current dot. If you comapre that with a standalone function that's not on the prototype, like my `addOne_f`, their `this` refers to window or some other context the script is running in. So they have no link whatsoever to the dots. Hence in the prototype, you can use `this` to mean, `the current dot`.

Comment: Inside the addOne_f function however you have to pass the dot as a parameter, since it has no relation whatsoever to the CreateDots class you have. There's more to it that this, but I'm trying to keep it as simple as I can. You can look up `javascript prototypal inheritance` for more information and tutorials.

Comment: Ah then I better start using it then! Thanks!